# how to read public folder from google drive on android

Tags: android

i want to create a comic reader project on android. In my database, i only save path to the chapter directory which was taken from folderID on google drive.  When user request to read comic, i want to through google client api to browse folder and get all file inside it. 
i've seen guilde on https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list
but i still do not understand how it works, specials parameter Drive, how can i get it?
Thanks for any supports.

```
private static List<File> retrieveAllFiles(Drive service) throws IOException {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    Files.List request = service.files().list();

    do {
      try {
        FileList files = request.execute();

        result.addAll(files.getItems());
        request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
        request.setPageToken(null);
      }
    } while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
             request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

    return result;
  }
```